# Такую отмазку даже любовница шефа не проглотит

Tags: наклонение

Оригинал: *Такую отмазку даже любовница шефа не проглотит.* (глагол в индикативе)

Русский перевод: *Такую отмазку даже любовница шефа не проглотила бы.* (глагол в сослагательном наклонении)

Помогите пожалуйста в следующем вопросе: Мне надо объяснить почему переводчик не последовал оригиналу в выборе наклонения и использовал сослагательное наклонение вместо индикатив. Я указала что переводчик благодаря использованию сослагательного наклонения еще особеннее подчеркнул контрфактивность ситуации. Скажите пожалуйста, я не носитель языка поэтому не могу это чувствовать - это ошибочно думать, что вариант с сослагательным наклонением звучит экспрессивнее чем с индикатив?

Большое спасибо!

Comment: И все же, важен контекст.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего, Вы правы.

**Контрфактивными** называют такие ситуации, которые не существовали в реальном мире и никогда не будут существовать, но рассматриваются говорящим как принадлежащие **к альтернативному миру.** [http://rusgram.ru/Сослагательное_наклонение](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Ситуация с любовницей моделируется говорящим, чтобы подчеркнуть несостоятельность "отмазки", она не реальная, а выдуманная.

Но такое значение лучше выражает **именно сослагательное наклонение**.

Вариант с индикативом приближает нас к реальности, но в данном случае этого не нужно.

Comment: Уточнение. По-моему,  "выдуманным" является не отмазка, а ее "испытание" на любовнице шефа.  "Даже любовница шефа не проглотит" предполагает, что отмазка будет реально предъявлена любовнице шефа.

Comment: Большое спасибо @Jasmin!